# boost test case for function taking user input

Tags: c++, boost-test

I have a function that takes in user input via std::cin:

```
std::getline(std::cin, in);
```

and creates a corresponding data structure by matching it with a regular expression. The function then returns this data structure.

I'm using boost.test and I want to create a unit test to check that the output data type is correct given some inputs. However I don't know how to go about it since the input isn't passed as an argument to the function.

EDIT: Is there a simple way to create a boost test case that feeds the function a string via standard input?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have access to the source code of the function that calls `std::getline`, then the easiest solution is to rewrite it as a wrapper of another function having the same signature and implementation, but taking an additional `std::istream&` parameter that is used in place of `std::cin`. For example, if you currently have:

```
my_struct my_func()
{
    //...

    std::getline(std::cin, in);

    //...
}
```

Then rewrite like this:

```
my_struct my_func(std::istream& is);

inline my_struct my_func()
{
    return my_func(std::cin);
}

my_struct my_func(std::istream& is)
{
    //...

    std::getline(is, in);

    //...
}
```

This way, you will be able to test the core functionality of `my_func` on constructed input sequences by passing `std::istringstream` objects into `my_func(std::istream&)`.

If you do not have access to the source code of the function that calls `std::getline`, then one trick that you can use is to replace the standard in descriptor. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278969/boost-how-to-create-a-thread-so-that-you-can-control-all-of-its-standard-output/4282240#4282240) for code that replaces the standard out descriptor and modify accordingly.

Comment: might be a stupid question, but should the wrapper class have a different name to the wrappee class?

Comment: @oadams: I presume you mean wrapper *function* and wrapped *function*, correct? C++ supports [function overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dhe1hce%28VS.80%29.aspx), so there can be more than one function named `my_func`.

Comment: oh, ok. yeah, function - whoops.